# Stopping services in remote processes

Tags: android, process, android-service

I have a background service called `MyService` in a remote (application specific) process called `MyApp:MyOtherProcess`.  **What happens to `MyApp:MyOtherProcess` and `MyService` when I swipe away the application?**

The Apps => Running Apps UI tells me I have 0 processes and 1 service.  I interpret this as `MyApp:MyOtherProcess` is not active but will wake up when  `MyService` is awoken.

Thinking `MyService` is still started, I then tried stopping the service.

Stop MyService:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
if (isMyOtherProcessRunning(context)) {
  //Test case: I have swiped away the application
  //Ahh, nothing is logged so I think MyService.onDestory is not invoked!
  //Is MyService still running???
  context.stopService(context, i);
} else {
  //Test case: I have not swiped away the application
  //Good, "destroying" is logged so MyService.onDestroy was invoked!
  context.stopService(context, i);
}
```

MyService:

```
public MyService : Service {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("MyService", "creating");
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("MyService", "starting");
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("MyService", "destroying");
  }
}
```

Helper:

```
public boolean isMyOtherProcessRunning(Context applicationContext) {
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
  for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
  {
    String processName = procInfos.get(i).processName;
    if(processName.equals("MyApp:MyOtherProcess")) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.myapp.MyService" android:process=":MyOtherProcess" />
```

To work around this I start `MyService` and immediately stop `MyService` if the process has been killed.  This seems like bad practice.  **Is restarting a service just to kill it a bad practice?**  I feel like I'm not understanding how `MyService` is maintained when the containing process is "killed"...is the process even being killed in the first place...can a process become just inactive...so lost!

*Current workaround*

Stop MyService:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
if (isMyOtherProcessRunning(context)) {
  //Test case: I have swiped away the application
  //Ahh, nothing is logged so I think MyService.onDestory is not invoked!
  //Is MyService still running???
  i.putExtra("stopImmediately", true);
  context.stopService(context, i);
} else {
  //Test case: I have not swiped away the application
  //Good, "destroying" is logged so MyService.onDestroy was invoked!
  context.stopService(context, i);
}
```

MyService:

```
public MyService : Service {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("MyService", "creating");
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("MyService", "starting");
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra("stopImmediately", false)) {
      this.stopSelf();
      return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("MyService", "destroying");
  }
}
```

*I'm running Android 4.4.4 API 19 on a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Genymotion version 2.3.1.*

Comment: i dont get it: you call stopService expecting onStartCommand to be called?

Comment: No, I call stopService and expect onDestroy to be called.

Comment: so why you pass "stopImmediately" extra in the intent for stopService? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm not understanding why stopService() is not calling onDestroy().  For a workaround, I try to start the command (which seems to wake the remote process).  Then immediately after I start the command I stop it.  My workaround works as expected where onStartCommand() and onDestroy() are both called.

Comment: what does stopService return?

Comment: Ooh good question!  I never checked.  It returns "true".  So I guess this means that the service is stopped but onDestroy() is never being called?

Comment: hmmm,  true is ok,  do you bind to that service too?

Comment: I'm not quite as familiar with binding to a service.  But I don't think I am.  MyService.onBind is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I think IntentService will help your case. Extend your service as IntentService rather then service, that you want to get stopped automatically.

IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Comment: IntentService seems really useful!  But is it necessary since I'm already in a different process?

Comment: But you are creating a service, isnt it ? Just create of type IntentService, the service you want to stop after doing the work. It is made for that purpose.

Comment: But I want my service to be long running.